# Can a JSF page be created dynamically?

Tags: java, jsf, model-view-controller

I am trying to display the fields on a jsf page dynamically on load by taking the page source from the database.

Based on some query the page source will be taken from the database and be put onto the screen and the components should be displayed on the screen dynamically.

So there will be a single screen but the screen source data will be coming from the database and the all the components on the screen will be displayed on the screen dynamically.

How can this be done?

Comment: Will the effort be worth the cost?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very robust approach. You can use technologies like Spring Roo to create a webapp based on database tables, but I wouldn't do this with JSF.

Comment: If your goal is a configurable UI, you'll almost certainly be better off by having the database contain a description of the custom fields (field name, type, etc) you want and then have JSF dynamically render the data into components, rather than have the database contain page source.  This sort of thing can get very complicated very quickly, so I think this is honestly a little too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, doing it in JSF or JSP is unlikely to be very easy/ or performant.

You may as well skip the hassle, and just write some simple Java classes to bind inputs & render HTML output yourself.

I've done a lot of 'advanced UI' work with big/ tree-structured/ configurable UI in different projects. Mostly with JSP, JSTL and Spring -- but the performance problems will be the same.

Another area you'll have to address, is loading all the components quickly. Typically we've use 'bulk loading' queries in Hibernate to load all children/ subtrees in a single query. This has been very effective.